# Скрыть GET запрос в адресной строке

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как такое url с запросом get:

```
https://xxx.ru/page/?page=update-1/
```

Через .htaccess заставить отображать как:

```
https://xxx.ru/page/update-1/
```

Comment: погугли pretty url, а скрыть запрос ты не можешь, это на стороне сервера обрабатывается

Comment: У меня всегда проблеvа с пониманием таких вопросов. Пользователь должен набирать и видеть `https://xxx.ru/page/update-1/` ?

Comment: @splash58,Да то есть пользователь переходет по ссылке `https://xxx.ru/page/update-1/` а сервер это принимает как `https://xxx.ru/page/?page=update-1` .Или же проста пользователь переходит по ссылке `https://xxx.ru/page/?page=update-1/` а в адресной строке видет `https://xxx.ru/page/update-1/`

Comment: второе выглядит невозможным. По первому варианту должен работать ответ Виктора Евлампьева. Почему не работает, непонятно. у вас есть что-то еще в htaccess'e ?

Comment: Я попробовал даже всё очистить .И поставить только его код всё ровно также.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Генератор .htaccess помог. http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Ну если выдаст ошибку 500 добавьте код:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page\/(.*?)/?$ page/?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Т.е. пользователь напишет xxx.ru/page/update-1/, а сервер увидет это как xxx.ru/page/?page=update-1/

Comment: Я попробовал вроде всё также стоит нет не какого изменения.

Comment: @Sauron, Возможно стоит добавить Options -Indexes

Comment: Тоже не помогло.